# Cannot install Kaltura oflaDemo on CentOS7

Tags: red5, kaltura

I'm currently setting up a Kaltura streaming server on CentOS 7 with mariaDB. When I come to the point the installation manual requires me to install oflaDemo via browser, I only get an empty list. No connection errors occour. The debug output states:

```
Host: vstream-dev.my.domain
Trying to connect
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Success
Got the application list
Got the application list
Got the application list
```

So, in theory there shouldn't be a problem.

- Firewall is down for testing/devel
- SELinux is off (permissive)
- The only error that ocoured during the installation process was `packet mysql-server is not installed`. But the manual states that I should use mariaDB on CentOS 7.
- I tried to clone https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples and link the ofla Demo folder to `/usr/lib/red5/webapps/` with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.

What I did:

I cloned the repo with the red5 examples: https://github.com/Red5/red5-examples and navigated into the subfolder oflaDemo (with `pom.xml`).

Then I had to install `maven` with

```
yum install -y maven
```

and do a maven build

```
mvn clean install
```

After that, I was able to grab the file `target/red5-example-oflaDemo-2.0.war`. I extracted this file into a folder `oflaDemo` in `/var/lib/red5/webapps` and restarted the server. Finally, I did `mkdir /usr/lib/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams` to create a folder for the streams.

After that, I was able to navigate to the demo via

http://my.domain:5080/oflaDemo/

Comment: Glad to see you solved it! Also you shouldn't need to create the streams directory manually.